# Login system for Android application

Tags: android, authentication

**The Plan:**

I'm developing an android application that is heavily database driven (as in, most of the content is fetched from a MySQL database via a RESTful service layer on my webserver).

Before any calls can be made to the API requesting data, the user has to b authenticated by passing his credentials where they are checked against the database. If the user is validated, I pass back an authorization token. If the user selected the 'Remember Me' option, this token will be saved locally for future use.

All future API calls need to contain this authorization token.

When the user wishes to logout, a call is sent back to the API to delete that token from the database, thereby invalidating it for future use. Local copy of the token is deleted as well.

---

**The Issue**

If the user **does not** logout, and simply closes the app (Home or back button) and did not have the 'Remember Me' option selected, I want to destroy the token at the server. How can this be done?

---

**Possible Solutions #1**

- If there is an `onExit` event that fires when the application exits, make a call to the API letting it know to destroy the token.

**Problems with this method are:**

- Does such an event exist, which is guaranteed to be raised in all
  conditions (home button, back button, program crash (I can live
  without this one) )?

---

**Possible Solutions #2**

- Maintain a `time of last activity` column in the database. If a call is made `x min` since the last activity, the token will be considered expired.

**Problems with this method are:**

- Added overhead of updating the time column in the database on every API call.
- Additionally, I will now have to store in the database if the user selected to be remembered, because in that situation the token cannot expire.

---

Which of the two solutions would you implement? Or is there another, better, way to implement this mechanism?

If you suggest #1, please advise which event it is that will serve my purpose.

Comment: Why do you keep authorization token at the server when user didn't select 'Remember Me' option ? Your authorization request could contain 1)credentials 2)'Remember Me' option. Remember token only if the option selected.

Comment: I was thinking that once I have received the credentials and verified the user, issuing a token would eliminate the need to pass username and password to the server everytime an API call is made, thus making it more secure. A token will be temporary while a password is more permanent. Also, having a token will allow the user to log out of any device remotely. (Access at friend's phone, forgot to logout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution is not applicable because:

1. There are no onExit event. (Of course you can create base activity and monitor there if the user pressed Home or back button just to figure out if the user hide the application or not. But that's very very complicated)
2. Do not rely on client logout. What if the user requested logout but the internet was not available at that time?
3. Android can simply kill your application at any time in low memory situation.

You'd better implement the second solution. Positives:

1. AFAIK, it's common practice when server controls the expiration of authorization token
2. No need to store in the database if the user selected to be remembered. Simply set expiration date to Integer.MAX_VALUE or something.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be handled by the server. The server must be the one to logout your user when your session dies after a specific time of inactivity. I'm not sure if there is a listener for the whole application if it dies but I never heard of one. Plus the user can always force kill the application without logging out via the task manager.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this solution as well. I don't think the overhead of maintaining the time of last activity should be noticeable but I will test and check for that.

Comment: Yes. I made a web service before and did that solution. What you can do is set the session to die after a certain time of inactivity and create a listener to listen on your session when it dies. You don't really have to save the last transaction time on your database. But it all depends if you're web service is stateful or stateless.